# rosbag.bag.ROSBagFormatException: Error reading header: expecting 606348583 bytes, read 871518

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, ros, rosbag

I am trying to create an UI interface where all the videos in ROS bag file will be played simultaneously. For this I have used threading concept like each thread for each video.

I am able to play all videos , but while playing the following error is thrown stopping the play.

```
class Main(QMainWindow):

...

...

class videoThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self,topic,bag,label):
        super().__init__()
        self.bag = bag
        self.topic = topic
        self.label = label
    def run(self):
        bridge = CvBridge()


       for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages(topics=[self.topic]):
            img_dcam = bridge.compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding="passthrough")

            rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(img_dcam, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            convertToQtFormat = QImage(rgbImage.data, rgbImage.shape[1], rgbImage.shape[0],
                                       QImage.Format_RGB888)
            convertToQtFormat = QPixmap.fromImage(convertToQtFormat)
            pixmap = QPixmap(convertToQtFormat)
            resizeImage = pixmap.scaled(300, 300, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.label.setPixmap(resizeImage)
            time.sleep(0.033)

def playVideo(self,topic):

    self.x = self.videoThread(topic,self.bag,self.label)
    self.x.start()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rosmanager_main.py", line 1276, in run
    for topic, msg, t in self.bag.read_messages(topics=[self.topic]):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2679, in read_messages
    yield self.seek_and_read_message_data_record((entry.chunk_pos, entry.offset), raw, return_connection_header)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2826, in seek_and_read_message_data_record
    header = _read_header(f)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1999, in _read_header
    raise ROSBagFormatException('Error reading header: %s' % str(ex))
rosbag.bag.ROSBagFormatException: Error reading header: expecting 606348583 bytes, read 871518
```